# Unable to call versioned API controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, versioning

I have a versioned webapi project consisting of 4 versioned controllers.

### ***Question Background:***

Currently I have a custom route method class - **shown at the bottom** - to select which controller to select based on a query 'version' string parameter passed in the URL - for example, to access the V2 (version 2) 'ProductV2Controller' and get all of the product objects the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:1487/api/product/?v=2/
```

My routes are defined as shown:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "NewProduct",
           routeTemplate: "api/product/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "product", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

        //*****Custom route selector*****
       config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new Selector.ControllerSelector(config));
```

### ***Where it's working:***

If I call a 'GetProductByName' method in a simple non-versioned controller called 'ProductController' this is fine and returns the DTO object based on the passed name. This is achieved with the following query string:

```
http://localhost:1487/api/product/Name=Table
```

### ***The issue:***

When I then try to do the same with a versioned controller, again with a query string to specify the controller version and a query string with a specified 'Name' parameter using the following URL:

```
http://localhost:1487/api/product/?v=2/?Name=Table
```

The method that should be getting hit:

```
public Product GetProductByName(string name)
    {
        return V2Ops.GetProductByName(name);
    }
```

This is being ignored and returning the simple 'ProductController' 'GET' all method.

This is how my 'ControllerSelector' class is returning the selected version controller URL to route too:

```
productV2/?Name=Table
```

This to me seems correct, ***it is*** selecting the correct controller, but I cant work out why it wont route to the 'GetProductByName' method!

### ***Update - Added the 'ControllerSelector' class:***

```
public class ControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    private HttpConfiguration _config;

    //Send config object to base constructor
    public ControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config):base(config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public override HttpControllerDescriptor SelectController(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string name;

        //Get the list of the Controllers i.e product/productV1
        var controllerList = GetControllerMapping();

        //Get the selected route api data.
        var routeData = request.GetRouteData();

        //Pull the selected routes controller name and convert it to a string.
        string controllerName = routeData.Values["controller"].ToString();

        HttpControllerDescriptor descriptor;

        //Check the controller list contains the controller implementation.
        if (controllerList.TryGetValue(controllerName, out descriptor))
        {
            //Call the GetVersionFromQueryString method passing the request object. This gives the api version.
            var version = GetVersionFromQueryString(request);

            //Construt the controller version.
            //If the returned version object wasn't null, i.e the request had a versioned controller, set the controller string.
            if (version != null)
            {
                name = controllerName + "V" + version;
            }

            //Else, simply return the standard 'product' controller.
            else
            {
                name = controllerName;
            }

            HttpControllerDescriptor versionedDescriptor;

            //If the controller list contains the controller plus its route return it.
            if (controllerList.TryGetValue(name, out versionedDescriptor))
            {
                return versionedDescriptor;
            }

            return descriptor;
        }

        return null;
    }

    //Check the route request version method.
    private object GetVersionFromQueryString(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        //Check the URL query 
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query);

        //Set the version parameter to version set at the URL.
        var version = query["v"];

        //If version is not null i.e a versioned controller has been called, return the version.
        if(version != null)
        {
            return version;
        }

        //else return null so the standard controller is called.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think its even legal to have two query strings, your query string is almost certainly being parsed differently than you think. Plus, it would help to see parts of your custom `IHttpControllerSelector` since that's where all the work is being done.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Thanks for you answer. I managed to sort this out but you led me on the correct path with mentioning two query strings were illegal. If you put this as your answer below I'll set it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are trying to use has two separate query strings in it; that isn't a legal syntax for an HTTP URL. The query parameters you are getting in your custom routing logic are almost certainly wrong. In particular, I would strongly suspect you aren't even seeing a parameter called 'Name' anywhere because it's not correctly formatted as a 'second' parameter. That would explain why your routing logic can't figure out where to send your request.

You should roll all of your parameters into a single query string and parse them out from there; you can always rebuild a new query string out of the remaining parameters if you need to send some, but not all, to the ultimate destination controller. e.g.:

```
Incoming: http://localhost:1487/api/product/?v=2&Name=Table
Outgoing: http://localhost:1487/api/productV2/?Name=Table
```

or whatever else you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've managed to sort this.

It was a simply case of the code was correct, but the URL wasn't:

The previous method I was using, i.e this with two query strings was wrong:

```
http://localhost:1487/api/product/?v=2/?Name=Table
```

This is the correct format. One single query:

```
http://localhost:1487/api/product/?v=2&Name=Table
```

This now works perfectly.